# What are the odds of drawing 23 cards and there is at least one ace?

Tags: probability, card-games

So my friends dad asked him this question and he asked it to me. None of us know the answer, and while I tried to solve it, I'm not to sure if my math behind is right.

I solved it a number of ways each way gave me a different answer, so i'll just show you the last way i solved it was, and then if someone can tell me how its solved.

The odds that one is an ace is 1 - P(not an ace)
Which  is 1 - ( 48C23 / 52C23) = ~90%

Im not too confident about this because its odd that Id get such a high percentage for only 23 cards.

Comment: You did it right!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's correct. Don't be surprised about the high probability: 1/13 of all the cards are aces. Therefore, om average, you'd already expect 1 ace when drawing 13 cards, and nearly 2 when drawing 23.

Comment: I..dont know why i didnt even make that connection. You are right, if 1/13 is an ace and i draw more...i should have an ace. Such a simple explanation. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Your calculation is correct, though the final approximation could be better:

$$1-\frac{\binom{48}{23}}{\binom{52}{23}}\approx0.91227\;.$$

In fact if we’re a little bit clever, we can even get the fraction exactly without using a very high-precision calculator:

$$\frac{\binom{48}{23}}{\binom{52}{23}}=\frac{\frac{48\cdot47\cdot\ldots\cdot26}{23!}}{\frac{52\cdot51\cdot\ldots\cdot30}{23!}}=\frac{29\cdot28\cdot27\cdot26}{52\cdot51\cdot50\cdot49}=\frac{29\cdot9}{17\cdot25\cdot7}=\frac{261}{2975}\;,$$

so the desired probability is

$$1-\frac{261}{2975}=\frac{2714}{2975}\;.$$